# VUE3 + IONIC - Property 'foo' does not exist on type '{ bar(): any; }'

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, ionic4, vuejs3

i have an error on vue3 + ionic, i try to make a component to get an image using `computed` and get a variable from `props`. Here is my code

Home.vue

```
<MenuIcon name="subscribe" fileName="subscribe.png" />
```

MyComponent.vue

```
export default { 
  name: 'MenuIcon',
  props: {
    name: String,
    fileName: String
  },
  computed: {
    iconPath(): any{     
      return require('../../public/assets/icon/icon menu/'+this.fileName)
    }
  }
}
```

i tried to change my `fileName` property to Object and change my `iconPath` property type to string or function, and still error. pls help

thanks before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code has no problem but it is weird there is no error of `this.filename` when you are using ionic + vue + ts with `export default {}`

Can you try adding `defineComponent` and see if it helps?

```js
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "MenuIcon",
  props: {
    name: String,
    fileName: String,
  },
  computed: {
    iconPath(): any {
      return require("../public/assets/icon/" + this.fileName);
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: its totally weird, i tried what u suggest before but still error, then i restart my pc and it works. thanks man